# merged list doesn't show in the terminal

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void out(string& str) {cout << str << " ";}

int main()
{
    list<string> lm;
    list<string> lp;
    string temp;
    cout << "List of Mat (quit to quit):\n";
    while (cin >> temp && temp != "quit")
        lm.push_back(temp);
    lm.sort();
    for_each(lm.begin(), lm.end(), out);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Mat completed.\n";
    cout << "List of Pat (quit to quit):\n";
    while (cin >> temp && temp != "quit")
        lp.push_back(temp);
    for_each(lp.begin(), lp.end(), out);
    cout << endl;

    list<string> merged;
    merge(lm.begin(), lm.end(), lp.begin(), lp.end(), merged.begin());
    cout << "Merged list (sorted):\n";
    merged.sort();
    merged.unique();
    for_each(merged.begin(), merged.end(), out);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tested the program by inputting "a t g c" for `lm`, and "u a k g" for `lp`. The sizes of `lm` and `lp` were both 4.

But after `merge(lm.begin(), lm.end(), lp.begin(), lp.end(), merged.begin());`, the size of merge seemed infinite and the merged couldn't show in the terminal.

I was wondering if there's something wrong with my using of `merge`, or there was other problem. Thanks!!!

Comment: Side note: `merge` requires two *sorted* collections. I don't think that `lp` is guaranteed to be sorted here; you're missing a call to `sort`

Comment: Note that [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) "[m]erges two sorted ranges [`first1`, `last1`) and [`first2`, `last2`) into one ***sorted*** range beginning at `d_first`." (extra emphasis mine). You don't need the `merged.sort()`.

Comment: On the topic @AndyG mentioned: You _could_ wrap the input + sorting business in a function that you just call twice.

Comment: And why not use [the lists own `merge` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge)?

Answer (score 2):

On these lines

```
list<string> merged;
merge(lm.begin(), lm.end(), lp.begin(), lp.end(), merged.begin());
```

To copy the members to `merged` you need to use an inserter

```
list<string> merged;
merge(lm.begin(), lm.end(), lp.begin(), lp.end(), std::back_inserter(merged));
```

Comment: May I ask why do I need a ```std::back_inserter``` in ```merge()``` ? It seems that ```merged.begin()``` can also be an Output Iterator.